# Mercurial: aborting during a branch-update merge

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch, undo

I had a working directory with uncommitted changes and updated to a different branch. Part way through the process of merging all the changed files, I realized that this was not what I wanted to do. Is there a way to recover from this? Is there a way to prevent it from happening again?

Mercurial version 1.8.4

The command executed was `hg update default`.

The branch I was in was a child of the default branch. No changes had been made to the default branch since the last merge from default to child.

Comment: I thought Mercurial doesn't let you update across branches (but I only have 1.5.4 so it might be new?)

Comment: @Neil: Is there another way to switch to a different branch?

Comment: @Neil: If the branches have been merged recently (the uncommitted changes are the only difference), then Mercurial does a merge to move the uncommitted changes over.

Comment: @Joel B Fant Ah, I hadn't read the question carefully enough, his working directory was effectively a descendant of the default branch via the recent merge from default to child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the danger of keeping uncommitted changes in your working copy.  Mercurial keeps no record of your working copy changes.  You are forced to rely on the files themselves.

It may be possible to recover if you:

1. Backup the repo (including the uncommitted changes) so you can try again if needed
2. `hg update <branch you want to be on>`
3. Carefully review your working copy

This will attempt to merge your working copy changes back into their original branch.  However, there is no guarantee that the result will be what you want.

To prevent this in the future, you should use [`hg update --check`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/update).  The `--check` option will abort the update if there are uncommitted local changes.

Comment: It looks like --check will abort regardless of whether I'm trying to update across branches. Is there a way to allow uncommitted changes in the working copy and update within a branch, but not to a different one? Maybe my problem was that it was technically to an ancestor of the current head.

Comment: @nmichaels: There are no built-in commands that do this, but you could consider creating an extension or `preupdate` hook.